# Moving read mail into new folders in outlook

Tags: vba, email, outlook

### I want to my Outlook email to run something like this:

- Email comes to inbox
- Email gets read
- All read emails get moved to a "_Reviewed" folder
- Certain emails automatically gets moved to a specific folder based upon things like subject, recipients or sender

I am new to programming and very new to writing scripts.

I am trying to write the main part of the script which would move every read message to my "_Reviewed" folder. But I keep getting this error

[image: Run-time error.png]

When I hit debug it brings me to the line

```
Set objFolderDst = objFolderSrc.folders("__Reviewed")
```

### I'm not sure whats causing the error.  Here is my whole code.

```
Sub ReadMailMover()  

Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set objNamespace = objOutlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set objFolderSrc = objNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
Set objFolderDst = objFolderSrc.folders("__Reviewed")  

Set colItems = objFolderSrc.Items
Set colfiltereditems = colItems.Restrict("[UnRead] = False")  

For intMessage = colfiltereditems.Count To 1 Step -1
colfiltereditems(intMessage).Move objFolderDst
Next


End Sub
```

I think that after I get this that I can get the rest of the script as it should just be repeated parts of this one.

[image: File Tree]

**Edits**
Changed @ToFile to __Reviewed which is what I had it as. I accidentally copied the code out of an earlier draft.

Added pic of file tree.  __Reviewed is not a sub folder to the inbox.

### Final Working Code

```
Sub ReadMailMover()

Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")  
Set objNamespace = objOutlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")  
Set objFolderSrc = objNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)  
Set objFolderDst = objFolderSrc.Parent.folders("__Reviewed")  

Set colitems = objFolderSrc.Items  
Set colfiltereditems = colitems.Restrict("[UnRead] = False")  

For intMessage = colfiltereditems.Count To 1 Step -1  
colfiltereditems(intMessage).Move objFolderDst  
Next  

End Sub
```

Comment: It looks as if the code has "@ToFile" where "__Reviewed" should be?  Also, is "__Reviewed" a subfolder to inbox?  If it's on the same level, then you'd need, objFolderSrc.Parent.Folders("__Reviewed")

Comment: That did it!  Thank you! Can you add this as an answer rather then a comment so I can give you credit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When __Reviewed is on the same level as your Inbox, then you'd have to access the Parent property:

```
Set objFolderDst = objFolderSrc.Parent.Folders("__Reviewed")
```

[MSDN Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa171818%28v=office.11%29.aspx)

Comment: What would I do if I wanted to further restrict? `...Restrict("[UnRead] = true" And "[SenderName] = John Doe")`     Or how do you format that?

Comment: It looks like that'd be something like : `Set colfiltereditems = colitems.Restrict("[UnRead] = False") Set colfiltereditems = colfiltereditems.Restrict("[SenderEmailAddress] = 'jonDoe@gmail.com'")` And you can keep restricting it down from there [reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff869597.aspx)