# Moving read items from a folder back to inbox

Tags: vba, outlook

I'm new to VBA and looking for a way to move read emails from a folder called "ForApproval" back into Inbox. Found this code on [Stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24069436/moving-read-mail-into-new-folders-in-outlook) and it works brilliantly, but when I try to reverse source and destination and put my folder name in - I'm getting: Run-time error '424': Object Required (see below screenshot)

Can someone have a quick look and say what's wrong in here?

**Original Code:**

```
    Sub ReadMailMover()

    Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")  

    Set objNamespace = objOutlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")  

    **Set objFolderSrc = objNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)**

    **Set objFolderDst = objFolderSrc.Parent.folders("__Reviewed")**  

    Set colitems = objFolderSrc.Items  

    Set colfiltereditems = colitems.Restrict("[UnRead] = False")  

    For intMessage = colfiltereditems.Count To 1 Step -1  

    colfiltereditems(intMessage).Move objFolderDst  

    Next  

    End Sub
```

**My reversed version:**

```
Sub ReadMailMover()

Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

Set objNamespace = objOutlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")

**Set objFolderSrc = objFolderSrc.Parent.Folders("ForApproval")**

**Set objFolderDst = objNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)**

Set colitems = objFolderSrc.Items

Set colfiltereditems = colitems.Restrict("[UnRead] = False")

For intMessage = colfiltereditems.Count To 1 Step -1

colfiltereditems(intMessage).Move objFolderDst

Next

End Sub
```

[image]

[Runtime Error I'm getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oe2xn.jpg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the reversed code, when you initialise your variable *objFolderSrc* it includes a reference to itself.

```
Set objFolderSrc = objFolderSrc.Parent.Folders("ForApproval")
```

At this point *objFolderSrc* is uninitialized.  It doesn't reference anything.  For this reason it cannot be used to define a location.

Try this instead:

```
Set objFolderSrc = application.GetNamespace("MAPI").GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Parent.Folders("ForApproval")
```

Here the circular reference has been replaced.  You source folder is referenced via the inbox.